# Pointer points to another pointer in structure

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, member, memory-address

I have structure named `temp` with member `n`:

```
struct temp
{
    int n;
}
```

I wish to declare a pointer `p` to access member `n`.

```
struct temp *p
```

How to access member `n` by another pointer `p1` which points to pointer `p`.

Comment: `temp *ptr = new temp; ptr->n = 7; delete ptr`

Comment: `const int my_fav_num = 7; temp val; temp* p = &val; temp** p1 = &p; (*p1)->n = my_fav_num;`

Comment: `temp a; temp *p = &a; temp **p1 = &p; (*p1)->n = 2;`

Comment: @Thomas Sablik. Please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access member `n` through a pointer to `p` with

```
temp a;
temp *p = &a;
temp **p1 = &p;
(*p1)->n = 2;
```

`p1` is a pointer to `p`. Dereferencing it gives a reference to `p`. `(*p1)` and `p` are equivalent.